# Meteor Iron-router keeps loading loadingtemplate forever

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just spent a lot of time trying to figure out why I never got passed (after I defined a loadingtemplate):

```
  waitOn: function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('...');
    }
```

It just kept showing the loadingtemplate.

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the autopublish feature, so remove it by typing

```
meteor remove autopublish
```

In your consol. (of course this requires setting up publications)